# Vue JS - Formulario modal donde pasar una imagen para mostrarla

Tags: javascript, vue.js, material-design, vuex

Uso Vue2JS y Vue Material y lo que intento hacer es en un grid colocar un botón para cada fila que abra un modal y muestre una foto.

En cada row tengo el contenido de la imagen del item "item" el código que tengo es este , abre el modal pero no muestra la imagen

```js
    <md-dialog :md-active.sync="showDialog">
      <md-dialog-title >Foto</md-dialog-title>

      <p v-model="value">  {{ value }} </p>

      <md-dialog-actions>
        <md-button class="md-primary" @click="showDialog = false">Cerrar</md-button>
      </md-dialog-actions>
    </md-dialog>
```

```js
        <md-table-cell md-label="Foto">
              <img :src="item.thumbnailPhotoUrl" v-model="value"  @click="showDialog = true"/>
        </md-table-cell>
```

Comment: Hola ilernet, puedes añadir el resto de codigo para que tu ejemplo se pueda probar?  Mira [ask] y [mcve] para más info. Un saludo

Comment: El resto de código no funcionará porque la información la carga de un Json mediante una llamada API. Gracias

Comment: Puedes hacer un ejemplo para tratar el tema de la imagen sin cargar la info de un JSON. Y añadir el JS y la referencia a vue.js para probarlo. Un saludo